# Duvida sobre encadeamento simples em c

Tags: c, c++

Eu queria saber o porque dos processos de remoção em encadeamentos terem dois ponteiros setados para o next

como esse exemplo dado

```
void 
remove (celula *p)
{
celula *lixo;
lixo = p->prox;
p->prox = lixo->prox;
free (lixo);
}
```

porque sempre tem algo desse tipo "p->prox = lixo->prox;"? poderiam me explicar obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escrever

```
p->prox = lixo->prox;
```

é a mesma coisa que

```
p->prox = p->prox->prox;
```

Você faz isso para poder remover o item do meio.

Ex: imagine a lista `4 5 6`

O `4` é o `p` e o `5` é o `lixo`

O `lixo->prox` é o `6`

Ao fazer `p->prox = lixo->prox` eu estou falando que `4->prox = 6`, então eu posso remover o `5` agora que a lista não irá quebrar.

Comment: Obrigado irmão estava com dificuldades